# jQuery li element select by ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

can anyone please help?

I have a HTML code like this.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><img src="img/topbararrowback.png" alt=""></a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="hide_filter">
                        <a href="#">Hide Filter</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

I try to add a .click event on li having id **hide_filter**.

What I have done is-

```
$("#hide_filter").click(function()
{
    alert('message');
});
```

And -

```
$(".navbar-left li").click(function() {
    alert(this.id); // id of clicked li by directly accessing DOMElement property
    alert($(this).attr('id')); // jQuery's .attr() method, same but more verbose
    alert($(this).html()); // gets innerHTML of clicked li
    alert($(this).text()); // gets text contents of clicked li
});
```

And -

```
    $('ul.selectedItems li#hide_filter').click(function()
{
    //$("p").hide();
    alert('message');
});
```

And -

```
$('#hide_filter')[0].click(function()
{
    //$("p").hide();
    alert('message');
});
```

But nothing works for me.

Thanks in advance for helping..

Comment: when the script is executed whether the said elements are present in the dom?

Comment: your first click handler should work if jquery is added and DOM is ready when event is attached.

Comment: All ways, except last, are correct. First is prefered. Do you have event handlers on `a` element inside targeted `li`? Maybe there is handler on `a` with `event.stopPropagination` method call?

Comment: Have you included `jquery.js` and put your code in DOMReady handler? `$(function() { /* code here */ });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually It works :)

```js
$("#hide_filter").click(function()
{
alert('message');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><img src="img/topbararrowback.png" alt=""></a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="hide_filter">
                        <a href="#">Hide Filter</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Comment: I am using Bootsrtap 3. Is it making problem on that?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have added the jquery library, You need to attach the event when DOM is loaded.i.e. on DOM ready event:

```
$(function(){//document ready function
 $("#hide_filter").click(function(){
    alert('message');
 });
});
```

### Working Demo

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.selectedItems` selector from your 3rd option

```
$('ul li#hide_filter').click(function()
{
    //$("p").hide();
    alert('message');
});
```

Remove index 0 from your 4th option

```
$('#hide_filter').click(function()
{
    //$("p").hide();
    alert('message');
});
```

Otherwise your 4 options are correct and will work fine. Kindly make sure you have written these codes inside ready event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide_filter").click(function()
    {
        alert('message');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your code is not eval.
Try put your code in body tag with function wrap like this

```js
$(function(){      //document ready function
 $("#hide_filter").on("click",function(){
    console.log('message');
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a problem with jquery libraries. Are they in conflict with other javascripts?